# Entity framework. Insert values from one entity class to another different one

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Here is my problem...

I've got one entity class, and I want to keep historical values from this table. Every time each record is changed, I want to insert a snapshot from this record into another table (with the same fields). I could do this field by field, but I'm sure there should be a simple way of doing this.

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
var t1 = context.TABLE1.Find(id);
var t2 = new TABLE2();
context.Entry(t2).CurrentValues.SetValues(t1);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I've found this [How to "transfer" the data from one table to another with EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862174/how-to-transfer-the-data-from-one-table-to-another-with-ef) but it doesn't work for me, because my tables can't do what is said on this post

```
t2.CurrentValues.SetValues(t1);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: any error or observable behavior with your code ? Is `new TABLE2();` a typo error ?

Comment: When I run this code I've got this exception: "Member 'CurrentValues' cannot be called for the entity of type 'TABLE2' because the entity does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet<TABLE2>."
This is because I haven't yet the historic record on the database (the names of the tables aren't the real ones)

Comment: then you must add TABLE2 to the context, that is declare it as an entity type. `class MyContext : DbContext { DbSet<Table1> T1 {get; set;} DbSet<Table2> T2 {get; set;}}`, and/or call `T2.Add(t2);`

Comment: Sorry, TABLE2 exist on the context. Is t2 the one that not already exits, because I want it to create values for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a package like [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper/) to create a mapping between the Table1 and Table2 classes. They have good documentation on how to get that set up. You could also override the SaveChange() method to handle the creation/saving of the historical record.