# Performing a SQL query in controller action ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm having a hard time performing query's in ASP.NET Core.
What I need to do: I have a index view with all sort of property's, next to the rows in my view I have a button, on button click it must perform a controller action, that controller action exists out of: A query which inserts the specific row into a new table and then deletes the row in the current table.

I am doing it this way now:

The controller action I created:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void MutatieButton(int? id)
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Mutatie SELECT * FROM Moederblad" + "DELETE FROM Moederblad WHERE Id="+ id;
            context.Database.OpenConnection();
            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

The button in the view:

```
 <input id="Mutatie" asp-route-id="@item.Id" type="button" value="Mutatie" onclick="MutatieButton()" />
```

The script code to perform controller action onclick:

```
function MutatieButton() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Moederblads")',
    async: true,
    success: function (msg) {
        ServiceSucceeded(msg);
    },
    error: function () {
        return "error";
    }
});
```

}

But I can't seem to figure it out.
I have read something about Unit of Work but it is very confusing to me, if I understand it correctly: You have a DAL where you put all the actions in like: Delete, update, insert, edit etc. And you call these actions in your controller to perform them?

Or is there a better practice doing this?

Comment: What kind of weird Sql Command is that....

Comment: I would suggest you to try and create a valid sql command first using sql command prompt or which sql IDE you have.

Comment: @GaganDeep Im still using LocalDB, so not any SQL IDE.

Comment: Not very much experience in SQL query's so it might be that it is weird. But in that query I try to Insert the row where I just clicked the button to another table, and after that delete the row from the main table @GaganDeep

Comment: You should create two sql command objects and run each command seperately. For integrity issues use SqlTransaction object. if both commands return successful result then commit otherwise rollback.

Comment: Thanks @GaganDeep will try.

Comment: refer this article for help with SqlTransaction https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/working-with-sqltransaction-class-in-ado-net/

Comment: @GaganDeep I think I have found something more wise to do, what do you think? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862174/how-to-transfer-the-data-from-one-table-to-another-with-ef

Comment: This is with entity framework.

Comment: What do you want to ask here @RoyKooiman? You don't like connecting SQL on Controller? Do you want to take them to another class? What you want to do is not clear.

Comment: @ibrahimozgon I dont mind the technique. It just has to work. I will explain again what I am trying to do: I have a line on a table in this case the mother page, next to each line there is a button, when that button is pressed a method is executed in the controller and the line has to be removed from the current page and inserted into the mutation table after which it can be seen on the mutation page. Not taking them to other class but to different table.

Comment: It would be more efficient just to set a boolean field on the existing table to indicate that the data has been processed, rather than delete everything and re-insert it somewhere else. Generally if you find yourself moving data between two tables with identical or near-identical sets of fields then you've got a database design flaw. A relational database should only have one place (i.e. table) to store data of the same type.

Comment: @ADyson it is for accountancy reasons. It is a automatic collection application. You have a mother page with all the data from the customers. Whenever a customer decides to stop, then the customer is a mutation and has to be moved to a different page and not be in the motherpage because on the end of month it picks a part of all the properties and converts to a excel file. It are indeed 2 pages with the same properties.

Comment: Being displayed in a different page of the application doesn't require the data to be in a different table in the database. It just requires each page to run a different query on the same table. Maybe you should study SQL  a little more and you'd see that a WHERE clause in your queries would solve this for you. What you're doing now is inefficient and an anti-pattern

Comment: Could u maybe send me a telegram message? @whatishapp3ning, I would like to hear ur approach then as what ur saying sound logical.

Comment: I don't use Telegram. But anyway I'm not sure there's all that much more to it. Create an extra `bit` field (maybe called "mutated" or something?) in your `Moederblad` table. Set the default value as 0, so all new rows entered start with 0 in that field. Then, if you want all the data for the "mother" page, then you query `SELECT * FROM Moederblad WHERE mutated = 0`. When you run the Mutation button, write `UPDATE Moederblad SET mutated = 1 WHERE ID = ?` (? being the ID of the mutated customer).

Comment: Lastly to get all mutated customers then it's (I hope obvious) that you write `SELECT * FROM Moederblad WHERE mutated = 1`.

Comment: Of course if you have more possible statuses than just those two then maybe you make it into an `int` field and have another Status table for which that column is a foreign key, listing the integer IDs and human-readable descriptions of all the possible statuses.

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** The DELETE statement you wrote in the code in your question is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely [using ADO.NET](http://bobby-tables.com/adodotnet). **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way that code is written, someone could easily steal, corrupt or even delete your data

Comment: @ADyson my gratitude is great. I will use a bool and then do a linq query in my controller like: Db.Moederblads.Where(bool == true).ToList(); and do the opposite for the other view. So when the row gets edited and the bool changes, it automatically goes to the other view :)

Comment: Exactly. You don't need to physically move the data around, you just need to change its properties. In fact you "mutate" its state... it's the exact meaning of the word (I English at least!) :-)