# Entity Framework - archive row to another table with references

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I would like to ask you is there any solution to solve my problem? I use Code First approach in my application (table names after // TableName).

Entities:

```
class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Owner : BaseEntity // Owners
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

class Animal : BaseEntity // Animals
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
}

class Dog : Animal { } // Dogs
class Cat : Animal { } // Cats
class DeathAnimal : Animal { } // DeathAnimals
```

I store animals id's in Cat/Dog tables with 1:1 relationship to Animal table. When a cat dies it should be "archived" and id from Cats table should be **moved** to DeathAnimals table but **references to Owners table should remain the same**. How can I achieve that?

I tried it this way but it seems not work for me:
[How to "transfer" the data from one table to another with EF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862174/how-to-transfer-the-data-from-one-table-to-another-with-ef)

I use EF Core 5.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading to EFC6 and using temporal tables? Might be a nice introductory use case..

Comment: (Temporal are usable in EFC5 if you are happy to use raw - https://www.eidias.com/blog/2021/5/14/entity-framework-core-5-support-for-sqlserver-temporal-table)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upgrade my EFC to version 6 :(

Comment: Temporal table seems to be nice solution, I will check this one and give you feedback.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I have used the approach which I linked before with combination of setting up IDENTITY_INSERT to OFF, then to ON in one transaction.